# Azure synapse studio connectivity using Private end point

Tags: endpoint, azure-synapse

I am trying to setup a secure connection to Azure synapse studio using private link hub and private endpoint as mentioned in the below doc,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network

However, it throws an error.

> "Unable to connect to serverless SQL pool because of a
> network/firewall issue"

Please note- We use a VPN to connect to on-premise company network from home and access the dedicated pool using a SQL authentication. This works absolutely fine.

The private endpoint and link hub are mounted on the same subnet as the one we use for dedicated pool. So I don't think there is any problem with allowing certain ports for serverless pool. Please correct me.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

> **Unable to connect to serverless SQL pool because of a network/firewall**
> **issue ?**

**Synapse Studio**

[image: Ref1]

Follow this instruction for troubleshooting  network and firewall:

1. When creating your ***workspace***, [***managed virtual network***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-managed-vnet) should be **enabled** and make sure to allow ***all IP addresses***.

> **Note:** If you do not enable it, your synapse studio will not be able to create a private endpoint. So if you fail to do this during synapse
> workspace creation. You will not be able to change this later and you
> will be a force to recreate the synapse workspace.

[image: Ref2]

2. Create a [***Managed private endpoint***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-create-managed-private-endpoints),  connect to your ***data source*** and check whether the ***managed private endpoint*** is approved or not.

[image: Ref3]

To know more details please **Refer** this link:

https://www.thedataguy.blog/azure-synapse-understanding-private-endpoints/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-setup-azure-synapse-analytics-with-private-endpoint/

[How to set up access control for your Azure Synapse workspace - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control)

Comment: Thanks. In my case, our team has created the workspace without Managed VNET. So this option is disabled in the workspace. However, I'd like to secure the workspace by bringing it under the existing VNET/ Subnet so that it can be accessed only through company VPN and not over public IP. I'll go through the links. But please shed some light on this.

Comment: I recreated the synapse workspace with managed private network enabled and allowing public IP at the time of creation and after then I created private end points for SQL on demand and dev and private link hub for Web. All under the same subnet. But when i connect to the customer VPN and try to access the workspace, it is still throwing an error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what resolved it for me. Hope this helps someone out there.

Used Terraform for_each loop to deploy the Private Endpoints. The Synapse Workspace is using a Managed Private Network. In order to disable Public Network Access, the Private Link Hub, plus the 3 Synapse-specific endpoints (for the sub-resources) are required.

Pre-Reqs:

- Private DNS Zones need to exist
- Private Link Hub (deployed via TF in same resource group as the Synapse Workspace)

#### main.tf

```
# Loop through Synapse subresource names, and create Private Endpoints to each of them 
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "this" {

  for_each = var.endpoints

  name                = lower("pep-syn-${var.location}-${var.environment}-${each.value["alias"]}")
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = lower("pep-syn-${var.location}-${var.environment}-${each.value["alias"]}")
    private_connection_resource_id = ("${each.key}" == "web") ? azurerm_synapse_private_link_hub.this.id : azurerm_synapse_workspace.this.id
    subresource_names              = ["${each.key}"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "${each.value["source_dns_zone_group_name"]}"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [var.private_dns_zone_config[each.value["source_dns_zone_group_name"]]]
  }

  tags = var.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}
```

#### variables.tf

```
variable "endpoints" {
  description = "Private Endpoint Connections required. 'web' (case-sensitive) is for the Workspace to the Private Link Hub, and Sql/Dev/SqlOnDemand (case-sensitive) are from the Synapse workspace"
  type        = map(map(string))
  default = {
    "Dev" = {
      alias                      = "studio"
      source_dns_zone_group_name = "privatelink_dev_azuresynapse_net"
    }
    "Sql" = {
      alias                      = "sqlpool"
      source_dns_zone_group_name = "privatelink_sql_azuresynapse_net"
    }
    "SqlOnDemand" = {
      alias                      = "sqlondemand"
      source_dns_zone_group_name = "privatelink_sql_azuresynapse_net"
    }
    "web" = {
      alias                      = "pvtlinkhub"
      source_dns_zone_group_name = "privatelink_azuresynapse_net"
    }
  }
}
```

Appendix:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network#step-4-create-private-endpoints-for-your-workspace-resource
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-link-resource